# How is the below program working without using malloc()?

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, malloc

I have below C program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

enum country_name
{
    Germany, France, Spain
};

int main()
{
    struct employee
    {
            char *name;
            int age;
            float bs;
            enum country_name country;
    };

    typedef struct employee EMPLOYEE;

    EMPLOYEE e;

    //e.name = malloc(30);
    e.name = "Manuel";
    e.age = 25;
    e.bs = 25000;
    e.country = Germany;

    printf("Name: %s\n",e.name);
    printf("Age: %d\n",e.age);
    printf("Salary: %f\n",e.bs);
    printf("Country: %d\n",e.country);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I have commented malloc(). I was expecting sometype of warning or error.

However when i run the program it gives expected output.

```
-bash-4.1$ ./a.out
Name: Manuel
Age: 25
Salary: 25000.000000
Country: 0
-bash-4.1$
```

I was thinking I NEED to use malloc() to allocate the memory. Isn't malloc() really required in this case ?

Edit: After reading answers below.

Ok, so I guess I was trying to do this, and see if commenting out malloc( ) would cause any error.

```
char nameHold[30] = "Manuel";
e.name = malloc(30);
strcpy(e.name, namoHold );
```

In this case there I get a "segmentation fault" if I do NOT use malloc().

Comment: String literals result in a pointer to a constant array of characters. You simply make your pointer point to the same array.

Comment: Note that if you had the `malloc()` and then used `e.name = "Manuel";`, you would have a memory leak.  To avoid that, you'd need to use `strcpy(e.name, "Manuel");` — you'd also need `free(e.name);` before the end of the function/program.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yup !! Got you. I have already edited my question and appended what I learnt in the end of my question. Thanks.

Comment: 'e' is an instance of the employee struct, located on the stack.  this line: 'e.name = "Manuel";'  setting the char pointer: 'e.name' to point to the string 'Manual' that is located in readonly memory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just having `"Manuel"` in your source code is enough for the compiler to allocate a read-only memory block containing the string `"Manuel"`. Your code assigns the address of this memory block to `e.name`.

Without the `malloc` call commented out, your code does *not* store the string "Manuel" into the memory allocated with `malloc`; instead, it allocates 100 bytes (and makes `e.name` point to the 100 byte block), then makes `e.name` point to the read-only string "Manuel" (so you now have no pointers to the 100 byte block).

Comment: So you mean that malloc() wasnt required at all in this case ?

Comment: @1Byn Not in *this* case, however be warned that the pointer `e.name` points to *constant* data so you can't change the string. That's why normally one uses `const char *` for pointing to string literals.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg technically you can change `e.name`, just not the contents of the memory points to. (you can't change `*e.name`)

Comment: @immibis Ok I found out what i was trying to do. Please see the note I have put at the end of my question (I have edited the question to append the note). Please comment if my understading is right.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah i got you !! You mean constant char * points to a constant string right ? Just as immibis said abouve i cant change *e.name in this case.